# Python: Mesh a voxels assembly to compute the surface area

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, mesh, voxel

I have a voxels assembly which represents a stone in 3D. It's a binarized numpy 3D array in which 1 is assigned to voxels which make up my stone and 0 elsewhere.
I want to:

1. create its meshed surface
2. calculate the surface area on it.

But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem if it can be usefull. Marching Cubes algorithm is good, but it doesn't work well on binarized arrays. So:
1) Gaussian Filter applied to the 3D array (scipy.filters)
2) Marching Cubes algorithm to mesh it (scikit-image tool)
3) Sum up the areas of triangles (scikit-image tool)

Answer (score 3):

I can see a few options depending on your application: 3D convex hull or marching cubes.

**3D convex hull**

First, you will need to obtain an array of all the voxel 3D coordinates where your array is equal to `1`

Later, you can use `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`. `Scipy` methods are basically a wrapper for the `qhull` library. When using `qhull`, one of the output options (`FA`) is to compute total area and volume.

You can find some more information here:
http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html
http://www.qhull.org/html/qconvex.htm

**Marching Cubes**

If you need to keep concavities, then the previous option will not be enough. Marching cubes will be a good alternative. There is already a python implementation in scikit-image.

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_marching_cubes.html

You will again need to obtain all points as in the previous case. You calculate the verbs/faces with:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#marching-cubes

And the you can calculate the area with:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#mesh-surface-area

Comment: Thanks, it  looks nice. I can easly obtain an array of the coordinates where I have 1. I suppose it is ---> ' coordinates = numpy.where(array==1) '. Now I'm going studying scipy.convexHull and I'll be back soon :-)

Comment: Let me know how it goes and if you don't mind, remember to accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: It's a nice alghoritm and works well. The problem arises when my stone has some concavity. It just find the shortest way, thus cutting out the concavity!

Comment: It's exactly what I'm doing! I've tried with a sphere in order to test the different methods but using the scikit_marching_cubes the difference (regarding the surface area from analytical solution) is 8%.. It's a lot! Using the convex_hull the difference is less than 1% :-(

Comment: That's expectable but I would not blame the methods. In this case, the issue is in how you are discretizing the sphere...

Comment: Yes, but even with a very high resolution (small voxel size) the difference is constant, always around 8%. I think the problem is in the "voxelated" nature of my sphere, because it's not smooth, even with high resolution. Therefore I still have my initial problem :-(

Comment: Are you aware of a way to calculate volume contained within a mesh created by Marching Cubes?